# Manage an object by switching its class

Tags: python

I have a data input file for a particular program. There are different kinds of data lines in the file, and for each kind of input line there is a corresponding class in another module I created previously. Minimal example:

```
#data module
class AnalysisObject: pass
class BoundaryNode(AnalysisObject): pass
class MaterialDefiniton(AnalysisObject): pass
```

It seemed like it would be a good idea to assign a class to each line depending on which kind of data it represents, and to have that object's corresponding `AnalysisObject` as a r/w property descriptor, so I have done that by first establishing an interface (I can't use an `abc.ABCMetaclass` for reasons explained below):

```
#data input file module

class LineBase():
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
    def analysis_object(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class BoundaryNodeLine(LineBase):
    @property
    def analysis_object(self):
        #parsing the string - just an example
        #the logic for each line type is different
        data = self.split()
        return data[5], data[7]
    @analysis_object.setter
    def analysis_object(self, bnode):
        self.line = "ANALYSIS NO XX BNODE NO {0} NODE {1}".format(*bnode)

class MaterialDefinitionLine(LineBase):
    -similar implementation to the above-
```

My problem is how to assign each line of the file lines to the correct class while maintaining separation between my data input module and my data module.

My idea for this is to first load each line into a subclass of `str`. This subclass can then reassign the object to the correct class (using `myobject.__class__ = NewClass`) when any of its methods are called.

This all seems to be working ok, however, I'm unsure about whether reassigning an object's class in this way is a good idea. It doesn't seem to be causing any problems for me yet, but I'm not particularly experienced and am not sure what to look for.

```
class DataLine(LineBase):
    def _switch_class(self,klass):
        self.__class__ = klass
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        self.__class__ = line_type_detector(self.line)
        return getattr(self, name)
```

Parenthetically: this class is the reason I can't make LineBase an `abc.ABCMetaclass` with:

```
@abc.abstract 
def analysis_object(self): etc. etc. etc.
```

...because then the class reassignment would never happen when `DataLine().analysis_object` gets called.

Detecting which class each line should be is not a problem; I have a simple `line_type_detector` for that:

```
def line_type_detector(data_line):
    -figure out what class the line should be-
    return ItShouldBeThisClass
```

Comment: Why do you try to enforce this super separation between your “data modules” and your “data input file modules”? It would be perfectly fine for the data module to have a kind of serialization facility to allow them to parse the string representation themselves.

Comment: I agree it would be, but as I explained in [my comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039165/manage-an-object-by-switching-its-class/28039682#comment44479762_28039682), I am likely to have multiple input file types (maybe even a handful), and "teaching" my `AnalysisObject`s how to make themselves from every possible type of input seemed to me like a mistake, which is why I have endeavored to keep it all separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when using different types to identify this kind of different data, the more specialized types would be expected to have additional properties or method that are special for them. For example a `MaterialDefiniton` might have information about the material which the base `AnalysisObject` would not. So the reason for choosing a different type would be to be able to store properties that are not common.

Now, if that’s not the case, and the types are merely for identification and not for state or behavior differences, then you just shouldn’t use different types at all. Just use one type, and have it have a property like `kind` which tells which data kind you are referring to. So you would have for example `obj.kind = 'materialdefinition'`, or `obj.kind = 'boundarynode'`.

But I’m going to assume that this is not the case, that those objects are actually different and that—when parsing a line—you would want to fill different properties with values depending on the line type.

So, what’s wrong with the data types being able to parse such lines themselves? Nothing, I would say. It’s very common to have types that are able to serialize or unserialize themselves. And I don’t think it would be a problem of missing seperation of concerns; after all, the type is making sure that its state can be stored in a file, or loaded from a file.

In Python, you could actually just implement a type’s `__repr__` method to get a string representation that can be saved to a file. `repr` is meant to give you something that fully represents the state of the object. And for parsing, you can just create a function that takes a string and returns one of the objects depending on what the function parses. For example:

```
def parse (line):
    data = line.split()
    if data[0] == 'material':
        obj = MaterialDefiniton()
        obj.material = data[1]
        obj.otherstuff = data[2]
    elif data[0] == 'boundary':
        obj = BoundaryNode()
        obj.boundary = data[1]
    else:
        obj = AnalysisObject()

    obj.raw_data = data
    return obj
```

You could also move the individual parsing of the type into the type’s constructor, so you can just pass the line to the objects and they’ll build themselves. Or you create a classmethod that explicitely parses the data:

```
class MaterialDefinition:
    @classmethod
    def parse (cls, data):
        obj = cls() # This is equivalent to `obj = MaterialDefinition()`
        obj.material = data[1]
        obj.otherstuff = data[2]
        return obj
```

And then you can just choose which object you need in the general `parse` function:

```
def parse (line):
    data = line.split()
    if data[0] == 'material':
        return MaterialDefinition.parse(data)
    elif data[0] == 'boundary':
        return BoundaryNode.parse(data)
    else:
        return AnalysisObject.parse(data)
```

You could even move that `parse` function’s logic completely into the `AnalysisObject.parse` method, so that one returns whatever subtype is most appropriate.

Comment: "...what’s wrong with the data types being able to parse such lines themselves?" Yes I see what you're saying here, but the problem is (and this wasn't in my question since it already felt too long, but I guess I should add it) is that in the future there will probably be other input files for other programs for the same data. So I don't want to tell the `AnalysisObject`s how to make themselves because I'd have to teach them 3, 4, perhaps even 6 different input formats. Separating it all out would allow me to come back and write sort of a "plug-in" later for new input files/programs.

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to create a plug-in schema that will extend the classes themselves by adding new methods. The `AnalysisObject`s could simply have the `parse(line)` method unimplemented... hmm. Now to think about which approach is better.

Comment: But then, there is still nothing wrong with your specialized parser (for this particular file format) referencing and creating those objects on its own. There is no need to for those additional intermediary line types. You can just parse the lines and create your analysis objects directly.

Comment: That's true. I guess that doesn't cost me anything. I guess the real problem I'm having is I've never written a plugin system knowing for certain I will be expanding it multiple times later on. Just trying to avoid causing myself problems later.

Comment: There’s no reason for a plugin system. Just keep it simple and have one parse function for each kind of file format you end up having. And each of those parser functions is responsible of giving you a collection of the real objects (so the line parsing, the type decision logic, and the object creation happens in that function).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to change the class of an object once it has been constructed. So I would rather assign the class at creation time. You can do that explicitely with a function `createLine` that would return an object of the appropriate subclass :

```
def createLine(data_line):
    typ = line_type_detector
    if (typ == BoundaryNodeLine):
        return BoundaryNodeLine(data_line)
    ...
```

You could also use a `__new__` special method in `LineBase` :

```
class LineBase:
    def __new__(cls, data_line):
        return createLine(data_line)
    ...
```

where createLine would be the same as above function.

Then you could simply create your objects with :

```
line = LineBase(data_line)
```

and directly get objects of correct subclass

Comment: I had considered this factory function idea, but didn't think about putting it inside of the `__new__` method. Although changing the class works (you said you didn't know how to do it; all you do is say `myobject.__class__ = OtherClass`, and it's done!), this approach is much more clear as to what is happening, and still allows me to initially instantiate every object using the same class! Very helpful suggestion.